# Float unordered lists (UL) next to one another, and stack them at the bottom of each other, with no margins or spaces

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-float, html-lists

I have multiple unordered lists (UL) elements. Please check the image below:[image: multiple UL floated left... I want also the UL elements to stack at bottom of each other]

what I want to do is float the ULs next to each other. The ULs have different lenghts of content (LIs), therefore some UL are longer than other. When I float ULs next to each other in a limited width div layer, at some point the last ULs float at the bottom / left. However... if there's a UL that is longer there will be some space. I wish the ULs to float left and to *stack* to each other, at the bottom of each UL element, without spaces. Is there a way to achieve this with HTML/CSS?

floating ULs left of each other is easy... but I don't know how to get rid of the margin

----- UPDATE ----

this is the code I use to generate the HTML... actually I changed it from ULs to TABLEs but it doesn't change my problem. I have a number of TABLEs which may vary from 1 to 8. The width of the container DIV where these tables will appear can host up to 4 columns. The TABLEs will have different amounts of ROWs therefore will differ in lengths.

```
$groups = array();
foreach ($related->posts as $post) {
    $groups[$post->post_type][] = $post;
}
foreach ($groups as $name => $posts) {
    printf('<table class="related-group related-%s "><tbody>', htmlspecialchars($name));
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        printf('<tr class="related-item"><td><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" rel="permalink">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->id, '32').'</a></td><td><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" rel="permalink">'.$post->post_title.'</a></td></tr>');
    }
echo '</tbody></table>';
}
```

Comment: Good question! I ran into the exact same problem today and I am surprised it still has not a CSS only solution after three years. I see some good suggestions in the answers though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although advices and suggestion given were indeed helpful,

I solved the problem with jQuery Masonry, a jQuery plugin

http://masonry.desandro.com/

I'm not sure whether there are better ways to do it, but this one just worked

Isotope, another jQuery plugin that looks similar to Masonry, could probably do the same job as Masonry but I haven't tested yet: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

thanks for reading and dropping by

Answer (score 1):

That would be possible if you stacked them vertically. This [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5d5eM/) illustrates your problem, the next row of items will start off where the longest ul reaches in the previous row. Instead of creating new columns for the new row, you could insert the ul's back into the original columns to stack the ul's vertically. Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ3C4/) to see the difference.

Sorry, don't know if you can reach those links. jsfiddle.net seems to be under heavy load right now.

Comment: thanks for the jsfiddle but unfortunately I'm not able to predict how many ULs I will have and since this HTML is generated by PHP I wouldn't be able to distribute ULs into DIVs, because the number of ULs will vary

Comment: as long as you insert them column by column it doesn't matter (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, [start over!] 1, 2, 3, 4).

Comment: I've added the PHP code I use to generate my HTML - actually since I prepared the image above yestrda, but in the meanwhile I switched from ULs to TABLEs for a design reason, it actually doesn't change the issue

Comment: tables should not be used for design layouts, only for tabular data. an easier way to go about this would be to create an empty column-based layout as I described, then use PHP to cycle through your "posts" and echo out some javascript to insert them one by one into the columns.

Comment: you're right but it was a temporary thing, I reverted to ULs while I was working at some CSS... I think the best would have some direct javascript, I'm searching for some jQuery plugin perhaps it does exist something that can be used

Comment: no need to use any fancy plugins, just give your columns ids and use jquery's [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) function. this will make sure each "post" you add is placed under the previous one in the column.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand; how do I create columns? Even though I know there will be max four coulmn how do I put, for example, the first UL and the 5th UL in the first column, the 2nd UL and the 6th UL in the second column and so on and so on? I found a plugin called masonry that does what I want, except it doesn't work in my setup :( sigh

Comment: oh I just got it work with masonry plugin http://http://masonry.desandro.com maybe your proposed solution was better, but I didn't understand it

Comment: @Fulvio: very neat plugin. basically does what I was trying to explain... but better. I may actually use that in an upcoming project. thanks for the update!

Comment: you're most welcome! thanks - this is another plugin, looks similar but I haven't tried it: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 1):

Well, this solution may not specifically answer your question but it may help you fix your problem:

You won't be able to do this using float in the way you propose. The only solution I can think of would be to divide the elements into grouping `DIV`s (or your block element of choice) which are floated left. Essentially, you put each `UL` which belongs on the same Y-Axis into a column element of some sort:

```
<div class="col">
    <ul><!-- LI elements here --></ul>
    <ul><!-- LI elements here --></ul>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <ul><!-- LI elements here --></ul>
    <ul><!-- LI elements here --></ul>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <ul><!-- LI elements here --></ul>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <ul><!-- LI elements here --></ul>
</div>
```

I know this isn't completely semantic because you're adding elements purely for presentational purposes however I don't see any other way to achieve this (unless you are able to use absolute/relative positioning - which might be feasible if you know the number of items in each list).

Alternatively, there's probably a jQuery plugin or something along those lines which would allow you to position the elements dynamically but I don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: unfortunately this won't work; I can't do this because the UL are generated by PHP, I won't know what column goes under what, the number of UL will vary according to a db query; I know howver there might be a maximum of 4 columns, but the number of ULs that will go in them may vary  (from 1 to 8...)

Comment: I guess you could do as Matt K suggested using PHP to distribute the ULs into the different columns - but that plugin you found is awesome! I might even bookmark that for later!

Comment: thanks Zac, in the end as you can see I fixed with the plugin, easy and fast no need reinventing the wheel (for now) :)

Comment: It may be worth writing that out as an answer and accepting it in case someone else is looking for a similar solution - I'm not sure if unanswered questions get as much traffic...