# Aligning floated elements of variable height inside a fixed width layer at the bottom of each other without margins or spaces between rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, positioning, css-float

I have a series of UL generated by the following PHP code:

```
$groups = array();
foreach ($related->posts as $post) {
    $groups[$post->post_type][] = $post;
    }
foreach ($groups as $name => $posts) {
    printf('<ul class="related-group related-%s ">', htmlspecialchars($name));
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        printf('<li class="related-item"><span><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" rel="permalink">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->id, '32').'</a></span><span><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" rel="permalink">'.$post->post_title.'</a></span></li>');
    }
echo '</ul>';
}
```

- Number of ULs will vary.
- Each UL has a variable number of LI (height) and a fixed width.
- Each UL is floated to the left in a fixed width container DIV.
- There will be probably a maximum of two rows of floated ULs of variable lenghts.

Now, the problem is that in this way the HTML generated by the PHP above will create rows where UL elements will stack at the bottom of the margin set by the tallest UL from the row above. What I want is to stack ULs at the bottom of each other without margin.

This jsfiddle illustrates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5d5eM/

I don't know how to change the above PHP in a way that lets me create columns to align ULs vertically and at the same time distirbute evenly the ULs horizontally.

Maybe there is some javascript / jquery solution... but I don't know one. Any suggestion?

thank you!

ps - this is a repost from a question originally posted here: [Float unordered lists (UL) next to one another, and stack them at the bottom of each other, with no margins or spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896306/float-unordered-lists-ul-next-to-one-another-and-stack-them-at-the-bottom-of) the reason why I reposted it is that I realized by the answers kindly given that it can't be done with simple CSS since my code is generated by PHP and there are some variables. The question posted before became a bit messy because of the edits and other issues raised so I thought of clearing it and reasking it more clearly.

Comment: You might want to have a look at: http://isotope.metafizzy.co

Comment: Hi I actually solved it with jquery masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/ very similar to Isotope, in future I want to compare the two - thanks for the hint! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know php, but i'm trying to make this work. Lets start from here.

```
   $groups = array();
    foreach ($related->posts as $post) {
        $groups[$post->post_type][] = $post;
    }
```

Get the size of $groups here.
for eg. $sizeof_groups = sizeof($groups);

If you divide $sizeof_groups by 4 (u said u need four columns), U'll get the number of rows u gonna need. eg, if $sizeof_groups is 4 (4 un-ordered lists), you just need 1 row.

so $numberOfRows = $sizeof_groups/4;

There can be remainder too. If there is, we gonna need one more "row".

```
if($sizeof_groups % 4 != 0 )
    $numberOfRows++;
```

Now

```
for(i=0 ; i<=4 ; i++) // you need four columns
{
    echo '<div class="myDiv">';
        for(j=0 ; j<=$numberOfRows; j++)
        {

              foreach ($groups as $name => $posts) {
                   printf('<div><ul class="related-group related-%s ">',                     htmlspecialchars($name));
                   foreach ($posts as $post) {
                         printf('<li class="related-item"><span><a                   href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" rel="permalink">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->id, '32').'</a></span><span><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" rel="permalink">'.$post->post_title.'</a></span></li>');
    }
echo '</ul></div>';
}
echo '</div>';


}
```

OLD COMMENT:

I guess you can tweak your php code to display two lists in one div. I hope this helps:

HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv">
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>



<div class="myDiv">
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>


<div class="myDiv">
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
   width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
}

.myDiv{
     width: 50 px;   
    float left;

}


br { clear: left; }
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your anwser. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it. Because the number of ULs is not known and it is variable. The height of the ULs is also variable. I don't know how to tweak the PHP code above to retain the HTML and insert the DIVs. There could be a solution counting the number of ULs generated. Each row would have four ULs (columns). However I woudln't know how to insert a DIV every column and calculate the number of rows to determine the ULs that should go inside each...

Comment: HI there, thanks for your update; in the meanwhile I found a solution with javascript, but yours mitght be cleaner and lighter, I'll have to test it out, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with jQuery Masonry, a jQuery plugin

http://masonry.desandro.com/

I'm not sure whether there are better ways to do it, but this one just worked

also Yoshi from this thread reported Isotope, another jQuery plugin that looks similar to Masonry, but I haven't tested yet: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

thanks for reading and dropping by