# How do I get the divs to float next to, and below each other

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float, positioning

I have a lot of divs with text in it, and I want them to nicely align next to each other and below each other.

(I've read somehwere that I should make a parent div for these, and give the parent a relative position and the child a absolute position, but this didn't work for me)

But it won't work.

[I found this lay-out with shows exactly what I want mine to do](http://hakim.se/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
<!--<div class="blockboxgrid">-->
    <div class="blockbox">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>
            Text
        </p>
    </div>
<!--</div>-->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*.blockboxgrid{
   position:relative; <<< I saw this example while googling, to make the area where the box is in relative, and the box itself absolute. But this didn't work for me either.
}*/

.blockbox {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border:8px solid #ff6b6b;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 330px;

    color:#000;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqrjLz9d/)

Comment: Better you can use <ul> and <li> tags and put all your div inside each <li> tag as a child element.

Comment: @frebinfrancis yes, that would work - same approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8896548/1163786 - This is a layout job for http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ or http://masonry.desandro.com/. Not really solveable by CSS alone, needs a grid recalculation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float unordered lists (UL) next to one another, and stack them at the bottom of each other, with no margins or spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896306/float-unordered-lists-ul-next-to-one-another-and-stack-them-at-the-bottom-of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site your are referring to uses a JavaScript package called Masonry:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

This type of grid layout cannot be achieved by CSS alone, so you need the
Masonry package.

Comment: I looked at his code and I saw the word "masonry" but I didn't know what it was. Will this fix all my problems then?

Comment: If you want a grid similar to the one you mentioned, Masonry will probably do it.  I think you would need to set it up and give it a try to be sure, but well worth the effort.

Comment: I worked... sort of. I need to adjust my margins but I can do that later. Thank you for this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zqrjLz9d/1/ Here you go.

`.block {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}`

Comment: My block class divides my website into multiple sections. Homepage, About, Contact, etc. I should've removed it from the question. Thanks anyway.